# vb.net Get arrow keys press whilst in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

While inside a textbox, i can get the enter and escape keypress but i cant get the arrows (up down left right) key press. Instead it moves the cursor inside the textbox. I guess i have to override this but how? I need to be able to catch these events **only when im inside the textbox,** ....so a form listener is out of the question(?)

```
Private Sub txtMytext_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Mytext.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
        MsgBox("Enter pressed!")
    End If

    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Escape) Then
        MsgBox("Escape pressed!")
    End If

    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Up) Then
        MsgBox("Up key pressed!") ' this never fires :(
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` instead, KeyPress doesn't support all the keys. It's by-design.

Comment: I'd say it'd really be easier if you used `KeyDown`. Then you get `KeyEventArgs` and those have a `KeyCode` property, where you can check `Keys.Up` directly.

Comment: @DatVM did that, worked thank you! i posted it as an answer below :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

posting an answer to my own question, after helpful comments from DatVM and MrPaulch:

Instead of `KeyPress` i used the `KeyDown` event:

```
Private Sub txtMyText_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtMyText.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        MsgBox("UP")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys)  As Boolean
    If msg.WParam.ToInt32() = CInt(Keys.Left) And txtMytext.Focused = True Then
        'your code
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

valter